# Why the arrayList always empty under Volley response result loop?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

The carList is declared as a public variable in the class, and the log shows that values are added in the array, yet when I call the list is empty, how to solve it with Volley response?

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
try {
    JSONArray resArray = response.getJSONArray("result");

    for(int i=0;i<resArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject car = resArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = car.getString("id");
        String brand = car.getString("brand");
        String created = car.getString("created");

        carList.add(new CarListItem(brand, plate_number));
        Log.d(TAG, "ADDED___: " +brand + " " + plate_number);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: did you create an instance before adding: `carList = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: I suspect you're not waiting for the asynchronous response to come back, so the list is empty when your code executes (because the response hasn't happened yet).

Comment: Yes, I created the instance before  `onResponse`, the method which is using the array is after the `RequestQueueSingleton` method.

Comment: @BenP. But the debug log shows the values are added to arrayList!

Answer (score 0):

@Benp
You right, the solution is to add the recycler adapter within the `onResponse` body as here:

```
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
  try {
    JSONArray resArray = response.getJSONArray("result");    
    for (int i = 0; i < resArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject car = resArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String id = car.getString("id");
      String brand = car.getString("brand");
      String created = car.getString("created");      
      carList.add(new CarListItem(car_id, brand, plateNumber, color));
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if (carList.size() > 0) {
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapterCarsList(carList);
    buildRecyclerView();
  }
}
```

It was simple, need a tiny clue to fix it ;)

Thanks for helping